# Default Number of Trees in Random Forest Implementation of Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, parameters, random-forest

I am using the [Random Forest model](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.mllib.tree.RandomForest.html) of Apache Spark. However, it does not mention the default number of trees used by the model. Is there is some way to know the default value of "numTrees" parameter?

Answer (score 0):

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier.html

Set to 20, as per this source.